# How to fix ".pop() function out of range"

Tags: python, list

Hey Stack Overflow community,

I am trying to do a simple thing - pop each i-th element from a given list and remove any leading/trailing spaces in each element.

The problem is - `list.pop(i)` function returns an `out of range` error, whenever I go through a `for i in range (0, len(games_list))` loop.

I was able to solve this by using `list.pop(0)` instead of `list.pop(i)`. Please help me understand why.

The actual code follows.

I've looked at both `range` and `.pop()` functions guides, but it didn't give me an answer to the question.

## Code

```
games_list = [
' The Movie: The Game',
' The Legend of Corgi',
' Dinosaur Diner']


for i in range(0, len(games_list)):
    temp = games_list.pop(0) 
    temp = temp.strip()
    games_list.append(temp)

print (games_list)
```

I expect the output to be the following:

```
['The Movie: The Game', 'The Legend of Corgi', 'Dinosaur Diner']
```

Comment: `.pop` *removes* an item from the list, so as you continue to iterate towards the *original* length of the list as it gets smaller you go past the (new) end of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pop index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182147/pop-index-out-of-range)

Comment: I can't reproduce that error either with the code you've posted, or with `games_list.pop(i)` in it (though that version doesn't strip all the strings correctly). Can you clarify exactly when you're getting the exceptions? Show the actually broken code, rather than fixed your fixed code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shortening the list while iterating to the original length, since `game_list.pop(i)` also removes the element at `i`.

In general, iterating over a list is better done by a foreach:

```
striped_games_list = []
for title in games_list:
    striped_games_list.append(title.strip())
game_titles = striped_games_list  # A better design would be to exclude this and simply use striped_game_list going forward
```

However, in your case I would recommend a list comprehension:

```
game_titles = [title.strip() for title in game_titles]
```

Comment: Oh, now I see what you and @JaredSmith mean.

I thought that by appending the item I don't change the list. However, I know understand why is that so.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is very non-Pythonic. You can directly iterate on the elements of a list instead of their indices and collect the stripped elements in another clean list, instead of popping and appending into the same list. Does that answer your question:

```
' The Movie: The Game',
' The Legend of Corgi',
' Dinosaur Diner']

new_list = []
for temp in games_list:
    temp = temp.strip()
    new_list.append(temp)

print (new_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my code is very non-Pythonic! :/

And thanks for the solution involving for ... in ...!:)
~Cheers

Comment: Why would you feel bad (the :/ thing) when someone points out something that you can improve? There is a concept called Pythonic, and it is very standard to say when something does not really follow a Pythonic approach, aka Non-Pythonic.